# Parametrize the parameter name in a call

Tags: python, pytest

I am working on testing (using pytest) of a number of related methods with a similar but not completely uniform API.  The critical difference at this point is a required parameter-name difference between two types of API:

```
# API 1
def action1(*, info, provider)

# API2
def action2(*, info, source)
```

I can parametrize a single test to handle both of these types identically, but I don't see a way to use the API parameter name -- `provider` vs `source` -- that could be provided by the test parameters.  Is this possible?

The alternative is to pass a wrapper function with a parameter set that remaps to the individual APIs, but I already have a lot of indirection and I would rather not add more.

Comment: I'm not completely clear what the specific technical step you're asking us how to accomplish is. Is the question how to _inspect_ a function at runtime to determine which parameter names it was defined with?

Comment: I mean, I would like parametrically *specify* the parameter name in the call to the API under test. Case 1 would call the passed-in function (`action1`) with the `provider` keyword, Case 2 would call the passed in function (`action1`) with the `source` keyword, in the same line of code.

Comment: ...so, if I understand correctly, we'd be looking at something like combining the test of which calling convention is applicable with the use of `**kwargs`, with that test deciding what the key in the dict we're expanding is?

Comment: With respect to "in the same line of code", I'd like to be sure I understand just what you mean (to avoid writing an answer that's sure to be rejected). Is the intent to have _all_ the code involved in this fit in one line, or to ensure that whatever is constructed can be _used_ on a short, easy-to-read line, even if it involves utility functions doing more work under the hood?

Comment: I meant the latter; I wanted to avoid an explicit `if` choosing between calling with `provider` vs calling with `src`; and I wanted to avoid a generic wrapper around the function call. Your answer satisfied both counts, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can parametrize your test with (i) the function you want to call and (ii) a dictionary containing any keyword arguments you want to call that function with.  For example:

```
import pytest

def action1(*, info, provider):
    return info, provider

def action2(*, info, source):
    return info, source

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
        'f, kwargs, expected', [
            (action1, dict(info=1, provider=2), (1, 2)),
            (action2, dict(info=3, source=4), (3, 4)),
        ]
)
def test_actions(f, kwargs, expected):
    assert f(**kwargs) == expected
```

Comment: That's nice, an approach I hadn't considered.